# Crossfilter - Cannot get filtered records from other groups (NOT from associate groups)

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm working with "airplane" data set from this reference http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

```
date,delay,distance,origin,destination
01010001,14,405,MCI,MDW
01010530,-11,370,LAX,PHX
...

  // Create the crossfilter for the relevant dimensions and groups.
  var flight = crossfilter(flights),
      all = flight.groupAll(),
      date = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.date; }),
      dates = date.group(d3.time.day),
      hour = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.date.getHours() + d.date.getMinutes() / 60; }),
      hours = hour.group(Math.floor),
      delay = flight.dimension(function(d) { return Math.max(-60, Math.min(149, d.delay)); }),
      delays = delay.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / 10) * 10; }),
      distance = flight.dimension(function(d) { return Math.min(1999, d.distance); }),
      distances = distance.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / 50) * 50; });
```

Following [document](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters) of Crossfilter, "groups don't observe the filters on their own dimension" => we can get filtered records from groups that theirs dimension are not filtered at this moment, can't we?

I have performed some test but this is not correct:

```
  console.dir(date.group().all()); // 50895 records
  console.dir(distance.group().all()); // 297 records

  date.filter([new Date(2001, 1, 1), new Date(2001, 2, 1)]);

  console.dir(date.group().all()); // 50895 records => this number still the same because we are filtering on its dimension
  console.dir(distance.group().all()); // 297 records => but this number still the same too. I don't know why
```

1. Could you please explain for me why number of "distance.group().all()" still the same as before we perform the filter? Am I missing something here?
2. If we really cannot get "filtered records" from "distance dimension" by this way, how can I achive this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, this is the expected behavior.

Crossfilter will create a "bin" in the group for every value it finds by applying the dimension key and group key functions. Then when a filter is applied, it will apply the reduce-remove function, which by default subtracts the count of rows removed.

The result is that empty bins still exist, but they have a value of 0.

**EDIT**: here is [the Crossfilter Gotchas entry with further explanation](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#bins-of-value-zero-are-still-displayed--group-bins-still-exist-after-filtering).

If you want to remove the zeros, you can use a "fake group" to do that.

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                //return Math.abs(d.value) > 0.00001; // if using floating-point numbers
                return d.value !== 0; // if integers only
            });
        }
    };
}
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins

This function wraps the group in an object which implements `.all()` by calling `source_group.all()` and then filters the result. So if you're using dc.js you could supply this fake group to your chart like so:

```
chart.group(remove_empty_bins(yourGroup));
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. The value of "value" of these record (297 records) have been changed by the filter. Not the number of records (297 will be persist).

Many thanks for your help and sorry for the late reponse!

Comment: Glad I could help & thanks for following up. I've created a Crossfilter Gotcha for this and linked it above.